# Qt/Socket IO - Client freezes at connection

Tags: c++, qt, socket.io

In a Qt project I am trying to connect to my NodeJS Socket IO server with the help of [this](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp)

When I execute this code:

```
std::cout << "BUTTON CLICKED" << std::endl;
sio::client h;
h.set_open_listener([&](){
   std::cout << "CONNECTION SUCCESS!" << std::endl;
});
h.connect("https://socket.asd.test:3000");
```

I get this result:

```
BUTTON CLICKED
Error: No active session
[2023-08-12 02:29:29] [connect] Successful connection
[2023-08-12 02:29:29] [connect] WebSocket Connection 127.0.0.1:3000 v-2 "WebSocket++/0.8.2" /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&t=1691796569 101
Error: No active session
```

And right after that my whole app freezes and crashes. Monitoring the server does not show any new connection.

If I stop the server and I try to connect from my C++ client I get this:

```
Error: No active session
[2023-08-12 02:43:53] [info] asio async_connect error: asio.system:61 (Connection refused)
[2023-08-12 02:43:53] [info] Error getting remote endpoint: asio.system:22 (Invalid argument)
[2023-08-12 02:43:53] [error] handle_connect error: Connection refused
[2023-08-12 02:43:53] [info] asio async_shutdown error: asio.ssl:167772436 (uninitialized)
Error: No active session
```

Which is normal and indicates that it can't access the server. Meaning that somehow when trying to connect to started server it freezes, but why ?

What am I doing wrong and I how can I fix it so that I can connect to my NodeJS Socket IO server with C++ client ?